# How to configure Liferay test database?

Tags: liferay, integration-testing

I am struggling setting up liferay integration tests. I found only one [article](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+Testing+Infrastructure) about this and would appreciate any help with it.

How do I configure database for liferay tests? Article mention putting them into

```
portal-test-ext.properties
```

but I have mine in :

```
myportlet/test
```

folder and it says :

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=
jdbc.default.password=
```

Nevertheless it still loads supersonic database (which causes some problems for me)

anybody have a hint?

Liferay documentation is just ludicrous.

Comment: Rule number one if you want qualified, quick and thorough help: Rant about the product you don't know about. Always earns sympathy

Comment: Agree with  @OlafKock

Answer (score 0):

Database configuration is portal wide and you can not specify it for just your portlet alone.

To configure the database, place `portal-test-ext.properties` in one of the following places:

1. Liferay's home directory.
2. Along side your `portal.properties` and `portal-ext.properties`